# Set the position of a UILabel to center

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, ios-autolayout

I have a view on that view I have a button and a label but the label will not align to be in center why so ever, its always on the right hand side of the view ....

pic what constraints I have set

[image: Constraints]

[image]

Comment: If you want the view centered, remove trailing and leading space to superview and give it a width. If you want the text centered, constraints are the wrong place to do it.

Comment: Your `align-center-x` and `leading-space`, `trailing-space` constraints are inconsistent.

Comment: Either remove the `align-center` constraint (As with 8 px leading and trailing space, it will be in center anyways). Or you could remove leading and trailing space, provide width constraint instead

Comment: You can change priority of leading and trailing constraints if you want them anyway.

Comment: @NSNoob I removed the align center constraints but that is not doing anything

Comment: @TamoDaleko That's not possible. Show us your desired output and current output. I think you are trying to create align-center-y and align-center-x but you are wording it wrongly as "align center x"

Comment: @NSNoob there you go I posted a pic so lbl should be aligned to the center

Comment: @TamoDaleko Your target label is "Don't have LAAX login?" right? As you can see, your text is smaller than what is required to cover screen as you desire. Your label is being aligned alright (You can test it by debugging "Color blended layers" in simulator ), your text however is aligned to the left. What you need here is text alignment. I am assuming that it is the string. If you are using an attributed string which contains "Create one" as well, that will be a different thing

Comment: @JörnBuitink already pointed you in that direction.

Comment: @NSNoob question by text alignment you mean the property that can be set in the storyboard ? if yes then no I set it to center. And its all one string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `center X` constraint, you have trailing/leading for that. After this your UILabel will be centered in the superview, but the text inside won't:

```
| [Text      ] |
```

To center text, just set UILabel's`textAlignment` to `NSTextAlignmentCenter` (centered), so it will be like:

```
| [   Text   ] |
```

Also I suggest to remove forced `height` constraint (you have it set to 28) and replace it with something like `top/bottom space` or like that.

Comment: thanks allot for your answer: since I am loading the string via a user defined runtime attribute how can I align the string